# CS Cart: How to pass multiple variable from template using assign and recieve them in fucntion in cs-cart

Tags: cs-cart

This is working

```
{assign var="order_notes" value=$order_info.parent_order_id|fn_my_changes_get_order_data}
```

I am able to use the parent order id in the function but I need to send product id as well. Sp I am using

```
{assign var="order_notes" value=$oi.product_id+$order_info.parent_order_id|fn_my_changes_get_order_data}
```

but this is not working. I am able to receive only one variable in my function. Here is the function .

```
fn_my_changes_get_order_data($order_id,$product_id)
```

it is working for order_id only when I add product_id there it is showing error. Service unavailable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Its simple. Right format for smarty - {$order_id|fn_my_changes_get_order_data:$product_id}